# What are the pros and cons of Areas implemented as single projects vs multiple projects in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The app I'm working on is large enough to break up into areas, but before I do so, I was hoping to get a better idea of when to implement areas in a single project versus multiple projects.

This article only mentions team size as a factor for choosing, but that doesn't really make sense to me
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461421(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommend that you use single-project areas, as we've made considerable strides in its support and stability.  The multi-project areas code is very fragile, and there is a higher-than-zero likelihood that it will be removed or pushed to Futures in the near future.

Comment: I am a developer on the project.

Comment: Does this answer still applies in 2013 now that we have Asp.Net MVC 5?

Comment: @codingbiz - multi-project areas haven't been supported for a long time at this point.

Comment: What is the advantage of this? I think it is better in the same project than adding another layer of complexity to a project set up. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: areas in other projects are good practice, just do not use visual studio without gulp or grunt. New mvc that come in 2016 will be prepared for this kind of solutions